# Is there a C# equivalent of VB.NET's "Static"?

Tags: vb.net, static

The VB.NET Static declaration:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx

The only reference I can find to this question is from 2008:

http://forums.asp.net/t/951620.aspx?what+is+the+equivalent+of+static+from+vb+net+in+c+

Is there an equivalent in recent versions of C#, or still not present? Is there anything particularly wrong about using Static in VB.NET?

Comment: It looks like syntactic sugar for a class variable, e.g., global variable, which certainly do exist in C#.

Comment: No, this feature does not exist in C#, I suspect because it doesn't provide tremendous value. All it does is limit the scope of a static field to a particular member.

Comment: @mellamokb It's more than that though, as in VB the static is scoped to that function.

Comment: @JohnKoerner: Ah, I see.  I've never used them before :)

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support it and probably won't be because it somehow violates object programming idea of state being part of object, not a method.

Of course one can say that it is only syntactic sugar, and he/she will be event quite right. But still, looking through class code, we expected description of its state variables as a fields of class. Otherwise we should find for it in each and every method.

So this can be simply seen about some high-level decision and your millage may vary here.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like the VB procedure-level `Static`, even if it's not "pure" enough for some folk.

1. You can set it in declaration and forget it:

   `Static oClient As HttpClient = New HttpClient()`
2. There's no checking whether a module-level variable needs to be instantiated or not:

   `If moClient Is Nothing Then moClient = New HttpClient()`

And, silly me, I always expect that there is equivalency between C#.NET and VB.NET but I've learned that clinging to that concept is folly, unfortunately.